# Rcpp with quad precision computation

Tags: r, rcpp

What is the best way to numerically compute things like the following within Rcpp?

`exp(-1500)/(exp(-1500)+exp(-1501))`

In many cases, the computation may require multi precision (for the exp), but the end result can be rounded to a usual double.

Via quadmath? Via boost?

If you stay in R (outside of Rcpp), there are really comfy wrappers to do the job:

```
library(Rmpfr)

a = mpfr(-1500,100)
b = mpfr(-1501,100)

exp(a)/(exp(a)+exp(b))
```

But how to access with rcpp?

Comment: Why not just compute the same thing in a way that *doesn't* require such an extreme exponent range?

Comment: For example, here, you could just add 1500 to all the arguments to `exp`.

Comment: this is just a minimal example ... I would like to apply in situations where I don't know what the numbers are.

Comment: Then *compute* the adjustment! Take the maximum argument (-1500 here) and subtract it from all the arguments.

Comment: I can also do series expansion, but that wasn't the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A quick way to get up and running is to install the `BH` package and use the Boost Multiprecision library, which provides [several extended precision floating point types](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats.html). For example, this code demos the [`float128`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/float128.html) and [`mpf_float_100`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/mpfr_float.html) types:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <boost/multiprecision/float128.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/mpfr.hpp>

namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::string qexp(double da = -1500.0, double db = -1501.0)
{
    mp::float128 a(da), b(db);
    mp::float128 res = mp::exp(a) / (mp::exp(a) + mp::exp(b));
    return res.convert_to<std::string>();
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::string mpfr_exp(double da = -1500.0, double db = -1501.0)
{
    mp::mpf_float_100 a(da), b(db);
    mp::mpf_float_100 res = mp::exp(a) / (mp::exp(a) + mp::exp(b));
    return res.convert_to<std::string>();
}
```

---

The latter requires adding flags for linking to the `libmpfr` and `libgmp` before compiling; the former does not, as it is a wrapper around GCC's built in  `__float128`:

```
Sys.setenv("PKG_LIBS" = "-lmpfr -lgmp")
Rcpp::sourceCpp('/tmp/quadexp.cpp')

qexp()
# [1] "0.731058578630004879251159241821836351"

mpfr_exp()
# [1] "0.731058578630004879251159241821836274365144640165056519276365907919040453070204639387474532075981245292174466493140773"
```

Comparing to `Rmpfr`,

```
library(Rmpfr)

a <- mpfr(-1500, 100)
b <- mpfr(-1501, 100)

exp(a) / (exp(a) + exp(b))
# 1 'mpfr' number of precision  100   bits 
# [1] 7.3105857863000487925115924182206e-1
```

Answer (score 1):

I fear you may be mostly confused.

Rcpp is a bridge between R and C++. It is neither a new language, nor a new system.

And in C++  you use something like [GNU gmplib](https://gmplib.org/) aka *The GNU Multiple Precision Arithmetic Library* which, of course, has already been wrapped for R as package [gmp](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gmp)

But if you want to write C++ functions, called from R, interfacing the GMP library -- you certainly.  It falls back to 'how do I write a C++ function callable from R which accesses an external library' -- and that question has been covered numerous times here too.

Comment: I don't feel confused, I was just looking for a minimal example. I'll just take a look the gmp sources then, thanks.

Comment: It's just like anything else requiring an external library: entirely doable, but you need to ensure the library is present on all relevant OSs.

Comment: For the record, the accepted answer states exactly what I said: _an external library is needed_.  It also kind enough to show one.